# Как сделать concat множества массивов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Как сделать concat массивов

сколько массивов будет в data точно не знаю. может быть разное количество

Сделал если два

```
const renderSlide = item => (slide, index)  => {
  if (!slideActive(slide, item)) {
    return { value: null }
  }

  return  {
    value: (
      <StatisticBox
        key={index}
        dataObj={item}
        slide={slide}
        id={slide.id}
        image={slide.image} 
        description={slide.description}
      />
    ),
    markup: false
  };
};


const data = store.getState().statistics;
const array1 = slides.map(renderSlide(data[0]));
const array2 = slides.map(renderSlide(data[1]));
const array = array1.concat(array2);
```

data  - это массив объектов. По сути нужно для каждого объекта вызвать slides.map(renderSlide(data[1])). он вернет массив и конкатенировать все в один массив

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> По сути нужно для каждого объекта вызвать `slides.map(renderSlide(data[1]))`

Это соответствует определению [метода `.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var arrays = data.map(el => slides.map(renderSlide(el)));
```

Далее осталось вызвать [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Вызывать его можно в цикле, либо воспользовавшись [методом `.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
var result = arrays.reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b));
```

Либо воспользовавшись [*spread оператором*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
var result = [].concat(...arrays);
```